# OpenCover for ASP.Net Core application running on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, code-coverage, iis-express, opencover

I'm trying to get Code Coverage for a Asp.Net Core application(DebugType - Full) running on IIS Express using OpenCover.

As specified [here](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3) I tried setting the environment variable and then run the OpenConsole. Only difference being that I'm trying to open using iisexpress.exe instead of VSIISExeLauncher.exe

```
set LAUNCHER_ARGS=-p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "exec \"C:\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\CoreWebApp.dll\"" -pidFile $([System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()) -wd "C:\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp"
set LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" -targetargs:"/config:""C:\CoreWebApp\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"" /site:CoreWebApp" -output:"Coverage.results.xml" -register:user –targetdir:"C:\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0"
```

I get 'HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure' when I hit any URL in the application.

Alternatively, if I try to run the application directly as below. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the server, the OpenCover also stops.

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"C:\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\CoreWebApp.dll" -output:"Coverage.results.xml" -register:user -oldStyle
```

Any idea how to use OpenCover with a Asp.Net Core application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked.

Set the environment variables.

```
set LAUNCHER_ARGS=-p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "exec ""C:\Users\baga\source\repos\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\CoreWebApp.dll"""
set LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe
```

Below command can be used if you want to just run the dot net core application in IIS express.

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:"C:\Users\baga\source\repos\CoreWebApp\.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:"CoreWebApp"
```

To get code coverage using OpenCover,

```
 OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" -targetargs:"/config:""C:\Users\baga\source\repos\CoreWebApp\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"" /site:CoreWebApp" -output:"c:\baga\Coverage.results.xml" -register:user –targetdir:"C:\Users\baga\source\repos\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0" -oldStyle
```

To generate the html report

```
ReportGenerator.exe -reports:"c:\baga\Coverage.*.xml" -targetdir:"Coveragehtml"
```