# Error when running IIS Express from command line with ASP.NET Core app (VS2017)

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I'm trying to run IISExpress manually, in order to add OpenCover coverage later.
This is with an .NET Core 2.2 app.
I am able to launch the app from within Visual Studio and everything is running fine.
Now i want to start it manually on command line.
I use the applicationhost.config generated by VS.

I followed what was said in the answer to [OpenCover for ASP.Net Core application running on IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233352/opencover-for-asp-net-core-application-running-on-iis-express?rq=1),
namely, adapted to my environment:

I'm doing this from a (non-admin) command prompt in
C:\Program Files\IIS Express>

```
set LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe
set LAUNCHER_ARGS=-p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "exec ""C:\Workspace\wk1\nSKEP\Dev\WebAccess\Dscp.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Dscp.Api.dll"""
iisexpress.exe /config:"C:\Workspace\wk1\nSKEP\Dev\WebAccess\.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:Dscp.Api
```

IISExpress launches and runs.
But when i try to connect to my site, i get the following response:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
Common causes of this issue:
* The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
* The in process request handler, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, was not referenced in the application.
* ANCM could not find dotnet.
Troubleshooting steps: Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526
```

I have visited the linked site and googled but didn't find any help.

In Win10 System Event viewer, i get the following error for "IIS Express AspNetCore Module V2":

```
Application 'C:\Workspace\wk1\nSKEP\Dev\WebAccess\Dscp.Api\' wasn't able to start. Application .dll was not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.dll
```

What is obviously intriguing is that it talks about VSIISExeLauncher.dll while i have specified VSIISExeLauncher.exe in the path.

What is wrong?

Comment: The new VSIISEExeLauncher works differently from what I analyzed in the initial blog post. You have to use Process Monitor/Process Explorer to analyze Visual Studio behavior once again, so as to know what to set.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be
    set LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
    set LAUNCHER_ARGS=exec "C:\Workspace\wk1\nSKEP\Dev\WebAccess\Dscp.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Dscp.Api.dll"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch IIS Express to run ASP.NET Core Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899494/launch-iis-express-to-run-asp-net-core-apps)